# Issue with maven in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven

Issue faced during open eclipse, I am using jdk1.8 and apache-maven-3.5.0.
I set path in environment variable as:

```
MAVEN_HOME  = E:\software\apache-maven-3.5.0
path = .......;%MAVEN_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;
```

I installed M2E plugin in eclipse luna.
But when I open eclipse, when I try this  `“Configure” -> “Convert to Maven Project”` ,I am  getting error:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Enabling Maven Dependency Management".
Illegal type at constant pool entry 288 in class org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ResolverConfigurationIO
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/eclipse/m2e/core/internal/project/ResolverConfigurationIO.stringAsProperties(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/Properties; @20: invokestatic
  Reason:
    Constant pool index 288 is invalid
  Bytecode:
    0000000: bb00 8959 b701 034c 2ac6 0019 2a12 06b6
    0000010: 00fc 4d2c b801 202b ba01 3200 00b9 011e
    0000020: 0200 2bb0                              
  Stackmap Table:
    append_frame(@34,Object[#137])
```

Also when I right click on my project, I did not find maven option, moreover there is no `m` symbol on my folder in eclipse.
What I do next?

Comment: Why not to use some latest Eclipse?

Answer (score -1):

The code [is here](https://github.com/eclipse/m2e-core/blob/f66704b877e3b22fd3fe845a559f870a34e0add5/org.eclipse.m2e.core/src/org/eclipse/m2e/core/internal/project/ResolverConfigurationIO.java#L126-L143).

You can see that kind of error in issue like:

- "[490988: Able to compile Interface.super construct in 1.7 project while using classes defined in 1.8 project](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=490988)"
- "[JDK-8037385 : constant pool errors with -target 1.7 and static default methods](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=8037385)"

In your case, double-check you OS, JDK, Eclipse (32 or 64bits), and m2e, to see if everything is running with the same JDK in 64 bits.

Try again with a more recent Eclipse, already including m2e.